# Pass parameter <option value selected="selected"> with python requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I need to set up how many items to see in webpage,
so I want to change parameter here:
from
`<option value="60">60/sivu </option>`

to
`<option value="60" selected="selected">60/sivu</option>`

Is it possible to do with Python package requests? How?
Thing is that if I am changing manually , then webpage address is not changing thus I cannot figure out how to do it.

Thank You !

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Why isn't the server running your webapp sending this data?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!   Please familiarize with these FAQs and repost your question -- (1) How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and (2) Why is voting important? - https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.  -- Happy Coding!

Comment: @Alderven - I have my code in another pc, but I'll try to write main points. I think You'll catch the idea. I am using requests package to render page and then lxml subpackage html to convert it to tree.: `r=requests.get(url)`  `html.fromstring(r.content)`  Thing is that for some web pages if I apply filter I see changes in address bar and then I can generate url according to pattern, but in this page address bar is not showing selections. I wonder why ? And then I cannot generate url to pass to requests.get. I hope it helps . Best Wishes.